# Ruby request to https - "in `read_nonblock': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)"

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

Here is my code

```
domain = 'http://www.google.com'
url = URI.parse "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,normalized_url%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='#{domain}'"
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new url.path
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request req}
puts res.body
```

and it gives me

```
/home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `block in transport_request'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1402:in `catch'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1402:in `transport_request'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from /home/alex/Documents/ruby_test1.rb:20:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:582:in `start'
    from /home/alex/Documents/ruby_test1.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: in your program line#20 contains which statement?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu, that's `Net::HTTP.start`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are several oddities in your code. The main is: since you use `SSL` you are to aknowledge `HTTP.start` about with `:use_ssl => url.scheme == 'https'`. `HTTP.Get` constructor awaits for an `URI`, not the path. The summing up:

```
domain = 'http://www.google.com'
url = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,normalized_url%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='#{domain}'")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new url 
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, 
        :use_ssl => url.scheme == 'https') {|http| http.request req}
puts res
```

Gives:

```
#<Net::HTTPOK:0x000000027d0558>
```

Comment: In my experience, I had to change
`Net::HTTP::Get.new url`
to
`Net::HTTP::Get.new url.request_uri`

(Net::HTTP::Get constructor seems to expect a string, not a uri)

Comment: @Oren_H It depends on the ruby version, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

[Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727341/2767755) answer was giving me an error -

```
`initialize': no implicit conversion of Hash into String (TypeError)
```

When I was using -

```
Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, :use_ssl => url.scheme == 'https')
```

My Ruby version is -

```
arup_ruby$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

Then, I modified the code as below :-

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

domain = 'http://www.google.com'
uri = URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,normalized_url%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url='#{domain}'")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
res = http.start { |http| http.request req }
puts res
# >> #<Net::HTTPOK:0x000001018f8520>
```

And it worked.